# Oracle Function Return CHAR

Tags: function, plsql, oracle11g

I wrote a function (FN_TEST_BE8) that returns a CHAR.

```
create or replace FUNCTION FN_TEST_BE8 
( P_PARAM1 IN Char
, P_PARAM2 IN Char
) RETURN Char AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN P_PARAM2;
END FN_TEST_BE8;
```

My problem is that when I run it it returns me a VARCHAR2 and for me it's a problem.

```
SELECT FN_TEST_BE8('XX','YY') RESULT
  FROM  DUAL
```

[image]

Since I use the function in where condiction and this forces me to cast the result:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1
 WHERE CHAR_2 = CAST(FN_TEST_BE8('XX','YY') AS CHAR(2));
 --  DOES NOT WORK --> WHERE CHAR_2 = FN_TEST_BE8('XX','YY');
```

The 'TABLE 1.CHAR_2' field is defined as CHAR (2).
If I use the WHERE CONDICTION commented with the label "NOT WORK" the statments does not extract data.
If I force the CAST on the result of the FUNCTION, the statements extracts the data correctly.

There are two point I don't understand

- The 'char' datatype is supported by PL/SQL. Why does the function not extract a CHAR but a VARCHAR2?
- I would have expected Oracle Database automatically converts a value from one CHAR datatype to VARCHAR2 datatype

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly does "DOES NOT WORK --> WHERE CHAR_2 = FN_TEST_BE8('XX','YY');" mean? Generally speaking, VARCHAR2 is *simpler* to use as CHAR is right-padded with spaces, up to its full length. Did you pay attention to it?

Comment: Hi, @Littlefoot. I edited the post and specified what I mean by "DOES NOT WORK" Yes, I have considered the difference between CHAR and VARCHAR2 but I cannot change the definition of the field on the DB.
If the Function extracts a VARCHAR2 when I compare a CHAR field with VARCHAR2 the select does not extract data
I do not understand why. I would have expected Oracle Database automatically converts a value from one CHAR datatype to VARCHAR2 datatype

Comment: I did some testing, posted as an answer (can't fit into a comment). Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

On my 11gXE, everything seems to be fine.

Table & function:

```
SQL> desc table1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CHAR_2                                             CHAR(2)

SQL> select * from table1;

CH
--
XX
YY

SQL> create or replace function fn_test_be8 (p_param1 in char, p_param2 in char)
  2     return char
  3  as
  4  begin
  5     return p_param2;
  6  end fn_test_be8;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing: all queries return the result:

```
SQL> select fn_test_be8 ('XX', 'YY') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
YY

SQL> select *
  2    from table1
  3   where char_2 = cast (fn_test_be8 ('XX', 'YY') as char (2));

CH
--
YY

SQL> select *
  2    from table1
  3   where char_2 = fn_test_be8 ('XX', 'YY');

CH
--
YY

SQL>
```

---

Which database version do you use? Could you do the same test, posting **exactly** what I did and the way I did it, executed in SQL*Plus?